# jquery/ajax doesnot work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

For some reason this does not work.  I have copy/paste the code, but it goes to the **html-echo.php** rather than displaying the result in the **htmlExampleTarget**

What am I doing wrong here.

Thanks

Dave

**edit:** sorry guys - here is the url - http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind form using ajaxForm 
    $('#htmlForm').ajaxForm({ 
        // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
        target: '#htmlExampleTarget', 

        // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
        // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
        success: function() { 
            $('#htmlExampleTarget').fadeIn('slow'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>



<div style="position:absolute; top:129px; left: 400px; width:500px; border:#000000 thin solid;">
      <form id="htmlForm" action="submit_form.php" method="post"> 
    Message: <input type="text" name="message" value="Hello HTML" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Echo as HTML" /> 
</form>
Reply: <div id="htmlExampleTarget"></div>
    </div>
```

and on the submit-form.php page

```
echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:20px">' . $_POST['message'] . '</div>';
```

Comment: Since you haven't shown us what *this* is, we can't know.

Comment: Please provide more details: code, who calls whom, ...

Comment: can you please be a bit more precise?

Comment: Show us **your** code, not the code you are attempting to copy/paste from.

Comment: Show us YOUR code. the jQuery Form plugin works fine for thousand of users, so you might want to consider that the error *might* be on your side.

Comment: If this is everything, then the problem is that you have no form. Btw linking to what you want to accomplish is fine, but as you see, does not help in helping you.

Comment: Not just a fragment of your code. Odds are you've put the wrong URL in the src attribute of a script element or something. We can't tell if we can only see *bits* of code copy/pasted from somewhere else.

Comment: You should always provide as much information as possible and as less information as necessary if you want someone to help you.

Comment: done guys, i was having trouble getting the code ported here..sorry

Comment: You still didn't tell us what *you* tried to code and what errors you got. You just copy&pasted jQeuery example code from their site.

Comment: @lutz: Actually he did this. From the link and code we can see that he wants to submit a form via ajax and update a div with its response. The problem is that this does not work and the form is submitted in the normal way i.e. displaying the target PHP page (his second sentence).

Answer (score 2):

You have two `<script>` elements. One of them loads jQuery, the other runs `ajaxForm`. You haven't loaded the *.js* file that contains the ajaxForm code.

See the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started):

> Include jQuery **and the Form Plugin external script files** and a short script to initialize the form

Since you haven't, the script errors when trying to run the function, so it doesn't prevent the default action. The code to make the Ajax request is missing (so that doesn't happen), and the default action runs (for the browser goes to the URI in the action attribute).

Comment: I have 2 files the submit_form.php is the second one, and contains the return parameters.

Comment: @dave: You can see such things easier if you use a debugger like Firebug for Firefox. I bet, you would have seen at the Firebug console that the method `ajaxForm` cannot be called.

Comment: @felix: actually i have not used firebug...never used firebug.